# c# XAML ProgressBar set gradient filling properly

Tags: c#, xaml, progress-bar, gradient

How do I set the gradient of a `ProgressBar`  in XAML to dynamic filling?

At the moment its like:

[image]

Code for both progress bars:

```
<ProgressBar.Foreground>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
       <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
          <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Rotation="270"/>
       </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
       <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="0"/>
       <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</ProgressBar.Foreground>
```

but I want to have the "end"color of the upper `ProgressBar`  in the green-yellowish color like directly below.
Means I want the progress bar full filled like the second bar and then "cut" the rest out (e.g. when I have 60% I want the 40% on the right not shown)

How do I do this properly?

Edit (found a solution):

After trying a couple of ways (drawing a rectangle with default color onto the bar etc) I figured out that I can modify the `offset` of `GradientStop` by code:

```
color_UL.Offset = 2.0 - ul_val / 100;
```

means I subtract the percentage that I want to display e.g. 30% (`ul_val = 30`) the Offset is set to 170% (1.7) but the bar itself shows 30% with the smooth and right color gradient. If I have 100% on the bar it calculates `2.0 - 1.0` which is 1 (like normal, shown in Bar #2 in picture 1).

I know this sounds all confusing, so here the picture as I wanted it to be:

[image: ProgressBar with fitting gradient]

Comment: So you want the light gray area not to show.... or..? Sorry amigo but it's not as clear trying to understand what you're saying you want.

Comment: I believe he wants the color to change as it's filling up, rather than having a gradient that stretches. Green at 25, yellow at 50 and red at 100.

Comment: sorry it's really hard to explain. I don't want the grey box to disappear, I want the colorgradient to be at the point, where it is below, so the end in bar 1 is not red, but the orangish color like it is at the point on bar 2

Comment: so in other words you want 3 colours to your gradient? if so can't you add <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5"/> between red and green? my WPF is a little rusty not so let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Take his bottom progress bar, cover it with your finger, slowly move your finger to the right. I think that's how he wants his bar to fill up.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. You want you initial progress to be full like the second one and the green/red colour to be shown as the progress increases.

Comment: @DamenEU I'm a little slow today! not enough caffeine I think!! :D but yea what you said is what I mean in my comment anyway.

Comment: So you just want to animate your gradient offsets?

Comment: @Chris W. no, not really animate, I just want the color an the right end to be not the final red, but in the position inbetween, that it would be on bar2 on same width

Comment: Sorry man but I'm definitely not visualizing what you want going off your description, seems other folks deciphered it but if you got something more descriptive of what you're looking for I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: If you've found a solution, you can post it as an answer using the Your Answer field below. You can then mark it as accepted later using the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:

After trying a couple of ways (drawing a rectangle with default color onto the bar etc) I figured out that I can modify the `offset` of `GradientStop` by code:

```
color_UL.Offset = 2.0 - ul_val / 100;
```

means I subtract the percentage that I want to display e.g. 30% (`ul_val = 30`) the Offset is set to 170% (1.7) but the bar itself shows 30% with the smooth and right color gradient. If I have 100% on the bar it calculates `2.0 - 1.0` which is 1 (like normal, shown in Bar #2 in picture 1).

I know this sounds all confusing, so here the picture as I wanted it to be:

[image: ProgressBar with fitting gradient]

Answer (score 3):

A second approach to achieving this layout is to set the background as the graded color and then use the foreground color as grey, remembering that your value of the progress bar needs to be

> 100-value

as you'll be setting the value for the gray area of the bar which starts at 100% (value = 0 OR no gray in the bar) and moves towards 0% (value = 100 OR entire bar is gray)

[image]100% (value = 100 - %)

[image]99% (value = 100 - %)

[image]50% (value = 100 - %)

[image]0% (value = 100 - %)

In your MainPage.xaml.cs (or where ever you need to call it)

```
var percentage = 75;
progressBar.Value = 100 - percentage;
```

In your MainPage.xaml

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="-82,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto"
                     Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="0" Foreground="Gray">
            <ProgressBar.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Rotation="270"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </ProgressBar.Background>
            <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
            </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
        </ProgressBar>
```

You might need to fiddle with the orientation of the progress bar so that it displays correctly, the above code is for a vertical bar which can be used for something like a fuel gauge.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in the XAML just the starting color (i.e. red(255,0,0) and calculate in your code the ending color performing a linear interpolation between the 100% color (i.e. LimeGreen(50,205,50). Binding ProgressColor (the color to calculate) in XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" >
        <ProgressBar.Foreground>
             <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0, 0.5" StartPoint="1, 0.5">
                  <GradientStop Color="{Binding ProgressColor, Mode=OneWay}" Offset="0"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
             </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ProgressBar.Foreground>
```

Then somewhere else do your maths:

```
public string ProgressColor
        {
        get
        {
            int R = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(255 - (255 - 50) * YourNeededPercentage));
            int G = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(205 * YourNeededPercentage));
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(50 * YourNeededPercentage));

            string ProgressColor = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", R, G, B);
            return ProgressColor;
        }
    }
```