# Custom ProgressBarIndicator WinRT

Tags: c#, image, progress-bar, winrt-xaml

I want to make custom `ProgressBar` with `ProgressBarIndicator` like image. Now i am creating `ImageBrush` and setting it to `ProgressBar`'s `Foreground` property:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="brush" Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="/Assets/image.png"/>

<ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource brush}"
             Background="{StaticResource GrayAppBrush}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             Value="{Binding Progress}"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             Maximum="1"
             Height="200"/>
```

But it work really strange:
[image]

Like you can see it stretching image horizontally and vertically. But i dont want it to stretching. I want image to fill all `ProgressBar` and becoming visible with running progress.
Here is something similar i want achieve:

[c# XAML ProgressBar set gradient filling properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288870/c-sharp-xaml-progressbar-set-gradient-filling-properly)

But it didn't work for me and i want image instead of gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the stretch property of the imageBrush eg:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="brush" Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/Assets/image.png"/>
```